# Relative Modules in Ambient Modules

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

As of TypeScript 1.6.2, there was a "fix" for a long term "defect" which made it impossible to import relative modules into ambient modules, now some of my code is breaking.  We utilise an AMD environment where we have a plugin module that loads CommonJS modules when executing under Node.  In particular I am using Intern as a testing framework and developing something that is designed to be used only as a CommonJS module.

For example, I used to have this declaration:

```
declare module 'intern/dojo/node!../../index' {
    import * as dtsGenerator from '../../index';
    export = dtsGenerator
}
```

But now I get `Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.`

I cannot figure out how to resolve a module absolutely within my ambient module for something contained within my project.  As of course the following indicates that `index` cannot be found:

```
declare module 'intern/dojo/node!../../index' {
    import * as dtsGenerator from 'index';
    export = dtsGenerator
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To dismiss errors, you can now use:

```
declare module '*';
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?